# Поиск файлов

Tags: c#, windows

Подскажите, как мне организовать поиск файлов любого формата в системе так, чтоб мне выводила программа  в textBox полные пути до файлов.

Comment: Совершенно не понятный вопрос. В чем ваша проблема? Определить абсолютный путь к файлу?

Comment: всё предельно понятно ) нужно организовать поиск например всех *.doc и получить расположение этих файлов!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd413233.aspx)

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.doc"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", file);
}
```